# Init jQuery over embedded sites

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a platform that is JS based. My clients copy and paste a google-analytic like code that auto deploys a custom set of JS functions as well as the latest jQuery 1.9 via Google.

Problem I'm falling into: My script dynamically loads jQuery into the page, but I'm unable to hook to 1.9, only the older version of jQuery that the client runs on their site.

I'm aware of the `noConflict` function, but I couldn't get it to work correctly because my script loads adjacent to the JS file that's loaded via the original page. So I gave up on that function, maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know which dom objects are available during falling into error? Ever tried to debug this in a console?

Comment: @TimVermaelen yes, this is all tracked / debugged via console.  The problem is that jQuery is not hooking to the latest appended version.  Nothing with the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to solve my own issue, here's how:

When my script loads on a client's page, it runs a interval "init function" every 10ms to hook on to a specific version of jquery I've set I.e. 2.0.3.  When it detects 2.0.3 it hooks I.e.

> var JQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);

2.0.3 is hooked to JQ, init function is killed, and prior version(s) of jQuery still execute with default $.().